# this.form.get is not a function?

Tags: javascript, angular

putting together a simple form, and upon submission I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _this.form.get is not a function
at VM46 vendor.js:29003
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at FormGroupDirective._updateDomValue (VM46 vendor.js:29002)
at FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (VM46 vendor.js:28820)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (VM46 vendor.js:12445)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (VM46 vendor.js:13951)
at checkAndUpdateNode (VM46 vendor.js:13894)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (VM46 vendor.js:14766)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (VM46 vendor.js:14707)
at Object.View_FeedformPage_0._co [as updateDirectives] (VM145
```

The function that I am running is very simple... I am just trying to log the value of the form to the console at the moment (which it does) but I am still throwing an error, which I need to address. My imports/function is as follows :

```
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
        public viewCtrl: ViewController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        public storage: Storage) {

    this.feedForm = this.formBuilder.group({

        description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(250)]]


    });
  }

addFeed(){

this.feedForm = this.feedForm.value;    
console.log(this.feedForm);

}
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<form [formGroup]="feedForm" (ngSubmit)="addFeed()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Update: </ion-label>
      <ion-textarea formControlName="description" placeholder="Leave Comment Here..."></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
   <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!feedForm.valid">Update</button>
</form>
```

The fact that I cannot find anything to reference except [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11171) tells me that I am overlooking something obvious. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Where's the class?

Comment: Why do you set `this.feedForm = this.feedForm.value` ? I could imagine the error occurs because you're assigning a value Angular can't work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the value of your form either logged or posted try this:

1- Delete `this.feedForm = this.feedForm.value;`
2- Change your console.log to this `console.log(this.feedForm.getRawValue());`

getRawValue will give you all fields values even if they are disabled